# Docker build command is deleting postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, docker-container

I am running Django project on server using docker. Every time when I call "docker-compose build" my postgresql database is being deleted. Please help, i want to protect my database from being deleted every time when i rebuild the project.
This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:

  monbat-tickets-db:
    container_name: monbat-tickets-db
    image: postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 5433
    ports:
      - 5433:5433
    environment:
      - LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
      - POSTGRES_USER=monbat-tickets
      - POSTGRES_DB=monbat-tickets
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=monbat-ticketspass
    networks:
      - monbat-tickets  
    volumes:
      # - ./docker_data/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
      - monbat-tickets-postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  monbat-tickets-web:
    build: .
    container_name: monbat-tickets-web
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - monbat-tickets-db
    expose:
      - 22000
    ports:
      - "22000:22000"
    environment:
      - DEBUG=0
      - POSTGRES_USER=monbat-tickets
      - POSTGRES_DB=monbat-tickets
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=monbat-ticketspass
      - POSTGRES_HOST=monbat-tickets-db
      - POSTGRES_PORT=5433
    networks:
      - monbat-tickets
    volumes:
      # - ./docker_data/media:/app/media/
      - monbat-tickets-app:/app/media/
networks:
  monbat-tickets:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  monbat-tickets-postgres:
    driver: local
  monbat-tickets-app:
    driver: local
```

And these are my containers(First two are the one we care about):

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
4a8cc52a075e        monbat_tickets_monbat-tickets-web   "/bin/bash entrypoin…"   23 seconds ago      Up 21 seconds       0.0.0.0:22000->22000/tcp           monbat-tickets-web
7e78832d7034        postgres                            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        5432/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5433->5433/tcp   monbat-tickets-db
c6d447060d45        monsite_monbat-web                  "/bin/bash entrypoin…"   7 weeks ago         Up 7 weeks          0.0.0.0:21000->21000/tcp           monbat-web
73caa39e2588        postgres                            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 months ago        Up 2 months         5432/tcp                           monbat-db
```

These are my volumes:

```
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               monbat_tickets_monbat-tickets-app
local               monbat_tickets_monbat-tickets-postgres
```

Thank you for the help! Feel free to ask for more information about this case :)

Comment: Why do you think your database is getting deleted?  Is your application actually configured to use PostgreSQL (I expect that `POSTGRES_PORT` to be wrong and you should get a connection error)?

Comment: @DavidMaze I have no idea. This is what i do.
`
if DEBUG:
    DATABASES = {
      'default': {
          'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
          'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
        }
    }
else:
  DATABASES = {
      'default': {
          'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
          'NAME': os.getenv('POSTGRES_DB', ''),
          'USER': os.getenv('POSTGRES_USER', ''),
          'PASSWORD': os.getenv('POSTGRES_PASSWORD', ''),
          'HOST': os.getenv('POSTGRES_HOST', ''),
       'PORT': os.getenv('POSTGRES_PORT', ''),
        }
    }
`

Comment: Are you using that SQLite configuration?  That would cause you to lose data whenever the container is recreated.  You should also be able to double-check whether data is getting into PostgreSQL at all using `psql` from your host system connecting to the published port of the database container.

Comment: (To clarify my parenthetical comment above, the PostgreSQL server will listen on port 5432 and no Docker-level configuration will change this.  In your client application `POSTGRES_PORT` must be the standard port 5432, the second `ports:` number for the database container must be 5432, and you can delete `expose:`; it does nothing.  Connections between containers only use the standard port numbers and don't look at `ports:` at all.)

Comment: @DavidMaze The problem was that i was using the SQLite database. My DEBUG variable was set to True. Stupid mistake but thanks to you I learned about the PostgreSQL configuration. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What reason do you have to use
`docker-compose build` when you can use `docker-compose up -d --build`.

Another question, Use **build** to recreate all the containers, wait for your information to be saved, when it is explicitly asking you to reload everything again.
Use `docker-compose up -d` to refresh your dockers.

> I am sorry to leave this as an answer, but my reputation does not
> allow me to comment.